# SQL 17.5 SSMS Install Fails

Tags: installation, ssms

On a Windows 10 computer, the SQL 17.5 SSMS installation fails.

From the logs, it appears that the error is in the VSTA 2015 installation.  Running that (vsta_setup.exe) directly fails with the following error in the log file (named dd_vsta_setup_(var.MajorVersion)_20180322092420.log):

```
[3F28:3D20][2018-03-22T09:26:37]i301: Applying execute package: vsta_hostingcore_x86, 
action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{11A9EF3E-6616-31B1-82BC-1080366FA34D}
v14.0.23829\packages\vsta_hostingcore_x86\vsta_hostingcore_x86.msi, arguments: 
' MSIFASTINSTALL="7"'

[23B0:2DCC][2018-03-22T09:26:52]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (vsta_hostingcore_x86) 
failed: Error Message Id: 1935 ErrorMessage: Error 1935.An error occurred during the 
installation of assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Utilities.
ProjectRetargetService.resources,fileVersion="14.0.23829.0",version="14.0.0.00000",
culture="zh-HANS",publicKeyToken="B03F5F7F11D50A3A",processorArchitecture="MSIL"'. Please
refer to Help and Support for more information. HRESULT: 0x80070005.
```

The full log can be [viewed here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VA8Wf3MKPNsGeQ5ydBnZde2nvyedQMMK).

One curious thing here is that the culture says "**zh-HANS**". However, this computer is purely English and has no Chinese installed on it.

Any suggestions on how to get this install to work?

Comment: so you tried to install from the vsta_setup.exe which was included in die SSMS install package? Did you try to download the VSTA 2015 installation from MS separatly? --> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49031

Comment: I've tried both ways with the same result.

Comment: Do you have the required "Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015" installed? It seems to be a required rentime for this installation

Comment: I tried that, and it wouldn't install because I have VS2017. Got the more recent one from https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads.  However, it has not helped.

Comment: Install SSMS 17.6 instead and get it from the official site (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms)

Comment: Thanks @Brian. Are you aware of a change that might solve this issue?  I'm downloading it now...

Comment: Nope. SSMS 17.6 also fails in the same way.

Comment: can you make a backup and delete this folder from GAC and try again? C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Utilities.ProjectRetargetService.resources

Comment: @ChunLiu It won't let me delete that folder. I'll keep looking for a way...

Comment: @ChinLiu Interestingly, there is one folder in that file: v4.0_14.0.0.0_zh-HANS_b03f5f7f11d50a3a

Comment: @ChunLiu I am unable to delete the 'resources' folder or the 'zh-HANS' folder in it but was able to delete the contents of the folder. It now says "The directory is not empty", but it is. Attempting install failed as before.

Comment: I managed to delete the `...zh-HANS...` folder from inside that folder. When I ran the install again, it was recreated but is empty.

Comment: Looking at a trace from Process monitor during the install, it appears that the installer also is denied access to that folder. That may be causing the installation failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could rename the `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Utilities.ProjectRetargetService.resources` folder but not delete it. Interestingly, the system "followed" the renamed folder and attempted to write to it during the install. Again, it failed and `Process Monitor` showed 'Access Denied' on that folder.

Given that an Administrator ID was not able to delete the empty folder, I suspected an NTFS issue.  Running `chkdsk` did not indicate a problem, but I ran `chkdsk /f /r` and rebooted.

The `chkdsk` log recorded in the Event Log showed no bad sectors, but did show:

```
Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...
Cleaning up 9861 unused index entries from index $SII of file 0x9.
Cleaning up 9861 unused index entries from index $SDH of file 0x9.
Cleaning up 9861 unused security descriptors.
...
Correcting errors in the Volume Bitmap.
```

Running the `vsta_setup` setup again worked. In the folder mentioned above, there are now folders for 12 languages, not just `zh-HANS`. I suspect that `zh-HANS` was simply the first that was to be written to the corrupted folder.

Comment: @chun-liu If you can add an answer, I can give you the bounty points, since your comment helped me focus in the actual problem area!